# I don't want, but I get state mutations in Array, when changing Date locale in computed property, in Vue app

Tags: vue.js, date, vuex, mutation, vue-i18n

I have Vue app with vueI18n for localization.
In my Array data, I have date string ("2018-01-04T01:10:54.673Z").
I try to change this string according to my locales.
First two times it works great, but then I get an error **([Vue warn]: Error in render: "RangeError: Invalid time value"**)
It is clear for me, that error because of `new Date()` get **wrong string format, after mutation my original state.**

What`s wrong???

store.js

```js
    getters: {
          notes: state => state.notes
        },
```

...

component.vue

```js
    computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["notes"]),
    getInfo() {
      const info = Array.from(this.notes);
      info.map(el => {
        el.createdAt = this.$d(new Date(el.createdAt), "short", i18n.locale);
        el.updatedAt = this.$d(new Date(el.updatedAt), "short", i18n.locale);
      });
      return info;
    },
```

this. is Console.log from my state
It was updated with code above

```
(10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, __ob__: Observer]
```

0:
**createdAt: "Jan 4, 2018"**

That`s what I get from API
0:
**createdAt: "2018-01-04T01:10:54.673Z"**

The main question is Why this code
info.map(el => {...}
mutate my state ???
I use private const info
and copy my state with the getter 'notes'  to it

Comment: Don't you need to run this function exactly once, when API responds? I mean, it doesn't make much sense trying to push through getInfo() function your start after it's filled with data.

Comment: You're modifying objects in a store directly. Use mutations and actions for this

Comment: Sorry, but can you point me wich code mutates my state?

Comment: – raina77ow    
getInfo() - computed property updates locales in my Objects data.
I use Vuetify data-tables in project